# how to set up xampp as online server?

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm using xampp as a testing host, but I want to be able to access it from anywhere. currently I can access it through localhost only, and through lan by typing my local ip, but not by typing my external ip from anywhere. I tried setting up apache vhosts, but I'm not sure what to put there, examples online aren't very clear, and I don't even know if it works. so if someone could give me a heads up, I'd appreciate!

Comment: [port forwarding](http://superuser.com/q/284051/47108).

Answer (score 1):

Log into your router and set up port forwarding to your computer with xampp on it. You probably want to forward port 80 (default for http) to your computer's LAN IP. Then you should be able to access your xampp setup over the Internet by going to your external IP address.

Answer (score 0):

- first you need to make sure the incoming traffic on port 80 is not blocked by your firewall or ISP - see [this video demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_open_port.html)
- then you need to configure your Router to forward: 
  incoming requests to your External IP port 80  towards your Internal IP port 80 - [video demo here](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_portforward.html)
- and finally test if port open - [see this demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_test.html)